# Codeigniter does not generates Captcha in CentOS 7, but works in windows

Tags: captcha, codeigniter-3, centos7, chmod, chown

This code:

```
{
    $this->load->helper('form');
    $this->load->helper('captcha');
    // Captcha configuration
    $config = array(
        'img_path'      => 'captcha/',
        'img_url'       => base_url().'captcha/',
        'img_width'     => '150',
        'img_height'    => 50,
        'word_length'   => 3,
        'font_size'     => 35,
        'pool'          => '0123456789',
    );
    $captcha = create_captcha($config);
    // Unset previous captcha and store new captcha word
    $this->session->unset_userdata('captchaCode');
    $this->session->set_userdata('captchaCode',$captcha['word']);
    // Send captcha image to view
    $data['captchaImg'] = $captcha['image'];
    $this->load->view('Login', $data);
}
```

generates captcha very well in windows, image created in captcha folder and showed in view.
The problem is that I moved my Codeiniter website to linux, CentOs7, I changed the www folder permission to 777 and the owner is apache but still no image is created in captcha folder and of course no captcha image appears in view.

```
 ls -ld www ===> drwxrwxrwx. 4 apache apache 33 Jun 11 17:18 www

 ls -ld www/html/CodeIgniter-3.1.3/captcha/ =======>
 drwxrwxrwx. 2 apache apache 6 Jun 15 06:06 www/html/CodeIgniter-3.1.3/captcha/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, CentOS has SELinux enabled by default. I choose the easy way to disable SELinux and now everything works fine.

```
sudo gedit /etc/sysconfig/selinux
```

change

```
SELinux=enforcing to SELinux=disabled
```